# Why must the name on my passport match the booking details?

Tags: tickets, passports, bookings, flight-status

I've recently booked some flights using my 'nickname' instead of my full birth name that appears on my passport (Rob verse Robert).  I've since contacted two airlines (RyanAir and Aer Lingus) and both told me I needed to correct the booking mistake.  The Aer Lingus rep mentioned that the specific destination was particularly strict and that I would need to sort this out.  Both airlines were happy to fix this for me, free of charge, but I'm left wondering 'Why does it matter?'

I was told 'security'.  But I don't understand how this increases security.  I've also been told airlines do it simply to find another reason to tack on a 'name change fee' but, in my experience, airlines make it quick, easy and free to update the name.

So, is there any real reason for this?  I can't imagine any scenario where it serves any purpose.

Comment: @pnuts - But what difference does it make?  If they'll let someone call up and change it...or even simply book it under a different name in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have any evidence for it but I suspect it might be necessary to satisfy [APIS requirements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advance_Passenger_Information_System). If you can provide a nickname, you could conceivably evade automatic checks against no-fly lists and similar databases.

Also, many people (e.g. from places like Indonesia) go by names that are completely different from what's on their passport. As @pnuts remarked in a comment, making sure hundreds of airlines and thousands of gate handling personnel all over the world share the same understanding of what's a nickname and what's not seems extremely difficult so it makes sense to enact a rigid rule that does not leave any discretion to airline reps.

So this is really about security (or “security theater”).

Comment: But the APIS requires the travel document number (expiry date and country of issue for passport).  Imagine if one John Smith was put on the no-fly list....a system that keys off name would mean all John Smiths are prevented from flying.

Comment: I personally know a few people who share names with people on certain no-fly lists. This is a problem for which those that create these no-fly lists do not provide a solution. In practice, the non-terrorist John Smith somehow has to prove he's not the terrorist John Smith. Typically, this gets resolved, but might involve having to show up at an airport six hours in advance or being put on a later flight.

Comment: @RobP. My guess is that those details might be crossed against databases of stolen documents. I don't know more than what's occasionally transpiring through the press but I don't think the US no-fly list is based solely on passport numbers.

Comment: The American no-fly list appears to be based on names. People who share names with people on the no-fly list must get a "Redress number" that they include with their flight details: http://www.dhs.gov/redress-control-numbers

Comment: But aren't Rob and Robert EXACTLY the same name?

Comment: @Rg7xgW6acQ3g Obviously not, it's a different set of letters ;) Importantly, people unfamiliar with American culture might not realize the connection at all, any robust international system cannot rely on this.

Comment: @Relaxed isn't Rob a short form of Robert, just like Max and Maximilian? Short forms are so common that airport security professionals should be at least acquainted with it...

Comment: @Rg7xgW6acQ3g Yes, it is... in some cultures, that's my point. Do you think airport security or ground handling staff in the US, Germany or the Netherlands (to name a few countries where short forms like this are in use) are familiar with Chinese or Indonesian naming customs? Even elsewhere in Europe the connection might not be obvious. And “Rob” is only the start of it, how about “Bob”? What about “Trijntje” for “Catarina”?

Comment: @Relaxed I would expect them to be able to deal with it. In an ideal world, where people do care...
Because the opposite work. Passengers are expected to know hundreds of strange rules, like not putting gas cartridges in checked luggage... but those things work in only one direction...

Comment: @Rg7xgW6acQ3g I don't think so. It's not only a matter of caring or being accommodating. Air transport faces very strict regulations and liability issues and has to deal with many different cultures. In this context, it's not possible to put this kind of decisions in the hand of local agents, it has to be based on bureaucratic processes and well-defined rules. Adding to that, plane tickets have never been so cheap and the system rely on hundreds of thousands of agents that are not nearly as well-trained as, say, pilots and could not possibly be without making air travel much more expensive.

Comment: Now, the use of short forms as nicknames is not simple or obvious in any way, it only seems that way because you are familiar with culture(s) where that's common. And naming habits are actually very diverse and complex so that training ground handling agents to be familiar with them would be very costly.

Comment: Sasha is short for Alexander, and Tania is short for Tatiana.  Everyone in Russia knows this.  Did you know this?

Comment: @Rg7xgW6acQ3g, I am living in an Anglo-Saxon country since 15 years so I am used to many of the nicknaming convention by now ... still, without being told explicitely, it took me nearly 10 years to connect that "Bill" was a shorthand for "William" (and I would certainly not enjoy having to explain that to a boarding agent or a custom officer unfamilliar with it...)